# Going from 10 output to 25 output CNN, but modified code is not working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is there any guide I can follow to help set up a CNN, using a sequential method? I have a dataset of over 100,000 images from Kaggle and am looking to categorize them into 25 different groups.

I understand I need to add Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, and Dense layers. But I'm unsure of how many to put and what parameters to set them at. I understand that I will have to do trial and error until I get the accuracy high but right now I am getting an accuracy of 0%. I found the following code snippet online which works for a 10 category classification and I'm trying to see how this would be changed to go to 25 groups.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I tried to change the input scale to input_shape=(200, 200, 1) to match my input image size, and I also changed the Final Dense layer from 10 to 25, however I am still getting 0% accuracy. Any advice is appreciated!

My model compile and fit are shown below:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Have you normalized your data (divided by 255 to put pixel values between 0 and 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are normalizing the data (if you aren't already) by dividing the images by 255 to get the pixel values to be between 0 and 1.

If you want to classify images into 25 classes the data will need to have the appropriate labels and you will need to change the last layer from 10 dense nodes to 25.

i.e.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 1))) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(25, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I did try having the Dense set to 25 nodes. I haven't done the normalization, my dataset is already greyscaled, do I still need to do that?

Comment: You definitely still need to normalize.